# Pandas Plot Epochs val_loss vs train_loss

Tags: pandas, dataframe, tensorflow

I have the dataframes

[DataFrame val_loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iheHc.png)

[DataFrame train_loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpzSG.png)

from a combination of Batches, NN and Learning Rates. I want to do this kind of plot in order to explain the model.

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAGow.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far that's failed? Your question should show an attempt (in code) so that we can correct it. Without that I would generically point you to Pandas plotting functions: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

Comment: Also, does this answer your question? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32281/how-can-i-plot-line-plots-based-on-an-input-python-dataframe

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73224502/edit) (it covers program output and input data). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.